# Calculate difference between column or subtraction of column in matrix report power BI

Tags: powerbi

How to calculate difference between column in matrix table in power BI? Below is the example

```
 Category   cool     warm    Diff   
 Colors         
      Blue       70    30    40  
      Black      50    50      0   
      Pink       40     60   -20
```

Category has many categories I have filtered out with cool and warm. I have tried

```
diff= CALCULATE(SUM(Value),Category="Cool") - CALCULATE(SUM(Value),Category="warm")`
```

but it's not working i am getting the same values of cool and warm in diff column when i am placing diff measure in the value pane.

Comment: Your measure may look like that:

diff = CALCULATE(SUM(Table[Value]), FILTER(ALL(Table[Category]), Table[Category] = "cool")

- 
CALCULATE(SUM(Table[Value]), FILTER(ALL(Table[Category]), Table[Category] = "warm")

Answer (score 0):

To add to this How to fix the duplicated columns in each of the subcategory.

I used the below DAX but somehow it's duplicated the calculated column "Delta TMCGP%" in all the subcategories. when i just want to show it at the end of the matrix table (Power BI)

Delta TMCGP% = CALCULATE([TMCGP%],
FILTER(
ALL(BC_Dashboard_V4_Standard[TYPE (groups)]),
BC_Dashboard_V4_Standard[TYPE (groups)]="4_CWV")
)
- CALCULATE([TMCGP%],
FILTER(
ALL(BC_Dashboard_V4_Standard[TYPE (groups)]),
BC_Dashboard_V4_Standard[TYPE (groups)]="5_POR"
)
)

[image]

Comment: Delta TEST = 
    VAR TMCGPpctCWV = DIVIDE(SUM(BC_Dashboard_V4_Standard[CWV_TMCGP]), SUM(BC_Dashboard_V4_Standard[CWV_REVENUE]))
    VAR TMCGPpctPOR = DIVIDE(SUM(BC_Dashboard_V4_Standard[POR_TMCGP]), SUM(BC_Dashboard_V4_Standard[POR_REVENUE]))
    VAR Result = TMCGPpctCWV - TMCGPpctPOR 
    RETURN
        Result



@@@@@I tried this but the result is still repeating the columns in other subcategories.